# Matching content between two point php regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex to replace

```
href="/test/any-word-here"
```

with

```
href="/search/theword.html"
```

I'm pretty new to regex's so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing but I came up with this

```
preg_replace('[href="/test/]([a-zA-Z])\"', "href=\"/search/$2.html\"", $content);
```

could anyone help me out?

Comment: What's the result of this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  The `[]` are undesirable.  You also need to capture the entire word and not just one letter.

```
preg_replace('#href="/test/(\w+)"#', 'href="/search/\1.html"', $content);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll spare you the habitual "you should not parse html with regex" response; most of your question still needs a regex :)

```
preg_replace('#href="/test/([^"]+)"#', 'href="/search/$1.html"', $content);
```

Instead of matching a positive character set, just match any characters until you hit the double quote character. Assuming proper prior escaping, that should work just fine.